# Get Current User for Delete Trigger - Spring MyBatis - Liquibase

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis, liquibase

I have a Spring services project that uses MyBatis and Liquibase.
I've made an audit table that has triggers for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

With INSERT/UPDATE I'm already storing the user id so it's not a problem to do NEW.USER_ID, but with DELETE I only have OLD.USER_ID which obviously doesn't reflect the current user making the change.

Excluding some info, I have this in liquibase (putting *s around what should change):

```
    <sql endDelimiter="|">
        CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_TRIGGER
        AFTER DELETE
        ON TABLE_NAME
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME_A (CHANGE_TYPE, CHANGE_ID, CHANGE_DATE)
        VALUES ('DELETE', **OLD.USER_ID**, now());
        END;
        |
    </sql>
```

So I'm not sure what to replace OLD.UPDATE_ID with.
The other examples I found often have to do with sql servers and mssql. So maybe I just failed as searching as I didn't find something that could work within spring/mybatis/liquibase/mysql.

Comment: I guess `NEW.USER_ID` just works because it is within you new created data row. Can't you just use the mysql function `user()`. Just like you use `now()`? And if you only want the username use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)`

Comment: NEW works for insert/update because they actually have new rows while delete is just removing a row. And how would I set user() to return what i want in the first place? Since it's a spring service, the mysql user() function will just return the user I'm using to have the service connected to the db. Not the user that called the service (i think).

Comment: The trigger is a spring service? I thought this is a database (i.e. mysql) trigger...

Comment: It's a database created/configured from spring project (that also contains services for inserting/updating/deleting). So it uses liquibase to set up the db. And MyBatis to run stuff against the db (mappers). So the user comes in through the services. We auth that they are allowed to make changes. Then we do all the changes they want. Problem is I can easily pass through their id to a MyBatis command. But triggers are pre-setup in liquibase which is the problem. Maybe I make an entry into the audit table and have it updated right away by something else with the right id.

Comment: I'm thinking since the trigger goes off the before the deletion. I can have mybatis delete the row, and then find the entry in the audit table and update it with the right id. Kind of hacky since it's a two step process.

Comment: Ok, now understand what you are trying to achieve. But I don't know how to do this with a mysql trigger since they don't accept parameters...

Comment: Yeah, I think my answer is basically that I can't do it alone through mysql triggers. Was hoping to shortcut the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filling out how I solved this.

I changed the base trigger to be

```
<sql endDelimiter="|">
        CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_TRIGGER
        AFTER DELETE
        ON TABLE_NAME
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME_A (CHANGE_TYPE, CHANGE_ID, CHANGE_DATE)
        VALUES ('DELETE', user(), now());
        END;
        |
</sql>
```

So that it fills the user field with something. Then after the deletion I wrote another mapper to go in and update the ID field to the current user calling my service.

```
<update id="updateAuditTableChangeIdAfterDeletion">
    UPDATE TABLE_NAME_A
    SET CHANGE_ID = #{1}
    WHERE UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = #{0}
      AND CHANGE_TYPE = 'DELETE'
</update>
```